# Preprocessing on the sources file of device driver

Tags: windows, device-driver, nmake

```
C_DEFINES=$(C_DEFINES) -D_PRODUCT_A
//C_DEFINES=$(C_DEFINES) -D_PRODUCT_B

#ifdef PRODUCT_A // <- I want to do doing like this in a sources file.
MOST_SOURCES= a.c b.c productA.c
#elif PRODUCT_B
MOST_SOURCES= a.c b.c productB.c
#endif
```

Is there a proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, because nmake (build?) only uses the first SOURCES line in the file

```
!IFDEF NEW_SRC
SOURCES=src1.c src2.c src3.c
!ELSE
SOURCRS=src3.c src4.c src5.c
!ENDIF
```

But, you can include environment variables like :

```
SOURCES=\
        purecall.c                  \
        driver_base.cpp             \
        capture.cpp                     \
        device.cpp                  \
        $(_rc_filename)
```

or you do something like :

```
makefile.inc
--------------
!IFDEF NEW_SRC
MY_SRC=src1.c src2.c src3.c
!ELSE
MY_SRC=src3.c src4.c src5.c
!ENDIF

!IF [echo SOURCES=$(MY_SRC) > sources.inc]
!ENDIF

sources
--------
NTTARGETFILE0=
TARGETNAME=mylib
TARGETTYPE=LIBRARY
.
.
.
!include sources.inc


mybuild.bat
-------------
build -Z0
build -Zcef
```

(This is taken from the [OSR online](http://www.osronline.com/) mailing list )